# Filter list of clients in paymill (preferably using the python pymill library)

Tags: python, paymill

Getting a list of clients from paymill using pymill works (almost) fine:

```
p = pymill.Pymill(private_key)
clients = p.get_clients
```

Yet the result only contains 20 entries and not the entry with a specific email address that I am willing to retrieve. When using the export_clients API method, all clients are returned as CSV including the client which I seek. The documentation[1] says that there is a possibility to sort and filter clients, yet it seems that pymill cannot do this. So I guess I will have to extend pymill to generate the correct REST requests? An alternative would be to parse the CSV client side, but this will not scale.

[1] https://www.paymill.com/en-gb/documentation-3/reference/api-reference/#sorting

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you increase the entries? This is made via count attribute. e.g: curl https://api.paymill.com/v2/clients?count=1000. Than you needn't download the csv.

Best,
Christian

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about this possibility. Yet AFAIK this is not supported by pymill (the python library)? Also, I guess this won't scale, since I will have to do the filtering client side and all clients need to be transferred via the network. I will accept this answer if nothing else is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to scan the CVS list to filter by email. Just use the filter option. It [works](https://www.paymill.com/en-gb/documentation-3/reference/api-reference/#filter-entries) like this:

GET https://api.paymill.com/v2/clients?email=urlencodedemail

Unfortunately the python wrapper does not support list filters and orders, but you are welcome to make a contribution. It's an open source project, i am sure they will accept a nice pull request :)